# Drawing Polygon Planes with SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

Does SceneKit not like planes (2D objects)? I have a bunch of polygons in 3D space (think panels of a roof) but they have no thickness. Sometimes I get weird results especially if all vertices have the same y value). I’m now wondering if I need to make each a 3D object with two faces and thin sides.

Are there restrictions when it comes making polygons? The documentation is unclear.